# Conditionally "preselecting" a radio button?

Tags: angular

In my application, I have a page where the user selects a focus item from a table (see simplified example below, circles represent radio buttons):

| Select | Name | Qty | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ○ | apple | 152 | crisp red fruit |
| ○ | banana | 253 | soft yellow fruit |
| ○ | cranberry | 124 | small red berry |
| ○ | etc. | etc. | etc. |

Each row is created like so from an `item` table, each item having the properties `item_id`, `name`, `qty`, and `desc`:

```
<tr ngFor="let i of items">
    <td><input id="selectedItem_{{i.item_id}}" type="radio" name="selecteditem" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [value]="i.item_id" (click)=selectItem(i.item_id) >
    <td>{{i.name}}</td>
    <td>{{i.qty}}</td>
    <td>{{i.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

The `selectItem(i.item_id)` function updates a global variable `global_selectedItem` to be `i.item_id`, because the value is used on other pages within the app.  That functionality works, but I would like it to be that if someone returns to this page, the radio button that corresponds to the currently selected item (i.e. when `global_selectedItem == i.item_id`) shows up as "checked".  How do I do this?  I've tried the following possibilities, none of which have worked.

```
<input id="selectedItem_{{i.item_id}}" type="radio" name="selecteditem" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [value]="i.item_id" (click)=selectItem(i.item_id) checked="global_selectedItem==i.item_id">

<input id="selectedItem_{{i.item_id}}" type="radio" name="selecteditem" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [value]="i.item_id" (click)=selectItem(i.item_id) [checked]="global_selectedItem==i.item_id">
```

EDIT: I have made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-is9zne?file=src/app/app.component.html) for the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you just have to write `[checked]=...` instead of just `checked=`?

Comment: The addition of `[]` didn't fix it.

Comment: Check you what's rendered in the document markup in the browser for one of those `<input>` fields? I suspect your `"global_selectedItem==i.item_id"` is threated as text, not a JavaScript expression.

Comment: The html text for the input (copied precisely) is `<input _ngcontent-c3="" name="selecteditem" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="selecteditem" ng-reflect-value="33" id="selectedItem_1715" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">`.  There is no difference between the one that should show up as selected and the others, save for the `id=` value.

Comment: @QuillAndSaber please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated and screen shots of what you want to happen!

Comment: I've added a stackblitz; link in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

2 fixes:

1. remove the ngModel
2. add brackets around checked attribute

So:

```
<input type="radio" 
  [name]="'selecteditem_' + i.item_id" 
  [value]="i.item_id" 
  [checked]="i.item_id===selectedItem.item_id" 
  (click)="selectItem(i.item_id)">
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mofmnb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html